# Enabling remote debugging in .htaccess for Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, xdebug

I'm trying to setup **Xdebug** for remote debugging in **PhpStorm**. The **Laravel** project I need to debug is hosted on a shared hosting, so I don't have direct access to the `php.ini`. The only way I can change PHP's options is via `.htaccess` and usually everything works fine.

This is the what I added into the `mylaravel.com/public/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    # Xdebug
    php_flag xdebug.remote_enable On
    php_value xdebug.idekey PHPSTORM
    php_flag xdebug.profiler_enable On
</IfModule>
```

But, every time I run `php -i`, there has been no overriding of the default flags / values for those configurations. I'm running the command inside the public folder `[~/mylaravel.com/public]$`.

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong? Is it possible that the hosting provider doesn't allow me to modify just those configurations (although I think is quite impossible it did it)?

Comment: I do not think that your hosting provider even has xdebug extension installed and enabled (it's production server!) as it slows down script execution quite a lot. Double check if extension is there (e.g. dedicated `php -m` or just `php -i` in command line ... or just `phpinfo()` output in the browser).

Comment: I don't think the command line php will use parameters from .htaccess - those are only read by apache.

Comment: @LazyOne Yep, I manually enabled the xdebug extension via cPanel, it's just not enabled by default the `remote` option

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt That's an interesting point, I should check it with `phpinfo()` instead of cli, then

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt Your hint was correct. Additionally, I found out that all the options inside `<IfModule mod_php7.c>` are ignored as the module doesn't exist, so I had to put them outside it. With those two corrections, now running `phpinfio()` correctly shows the overridden options

Comment: @Brigo Good to hear you got it working. Maybe you can answer your own question then, or delete it as it doesn't contain a lot of information for future visitors.